# How to get subcategory product name in product view

Tags: product

How to get subcategory product name in product view [image]

Comment: I didnot understand your question

Comment: If you want to ask a question ask properly, or just don't.

Answer (score 2):

try Below code

```
<?php $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
   foreach ($cats as $category_id) { $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
   echo $_cat->getName();
 }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your're in **`catalog > product > view.phtml`** or **`catalog > product > list.phtml`**

```
<?php foreach($_product->getCategoryCollection() as $_cat): ?>
<?php echo $_cat->getName() ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Otherwise, first line should get your the product:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

Would give your currently selected product.

While:

```
$_product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->load(45)
```

Would get you product 45.